# What is the vector space associated with the $U(1)$ character in the $c=1$ free boson?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

The U(1) character of the zero mode were
$$
\chi^{ U(1)}_{h(n=0,m=0)=0}=\frac{1}{\eta(\tau)}
$$
this was different from the so called Virasoro character
$$
\chi^{Vir}_0= \frac{1}{\eta(\tau)} ( 1-q)
$$
where the $(1-q)$ arise from the fact that
$$
L_{-1}|0\rangle =0
$$

However, I wasn't sure what the $U(1)$ character was, because $L_{-1}|0\rangle$ should still eliminate the level one decedent state.

After reading

1. [Correspondance between free fermion CFT partition function and Virasoro character](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524745/correspondance-between-free-fermion-cft-partition-function-and-virasoro-characte)
2. [Vacuum Character in Compactified Boson Partition Function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565628/vacuum-character-in-compactified-boson-partition-function/639836#639836)

[Sylvain Ribault](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/565628/vacuum-character-in-compactified-boson-partition-function/639836#639836)'s answer hinted that, the vector space of the representation of CFT(?) also contained a non-vanishing level one state $J_{-1}|0\rangle$ in the (?)vacuum module(?).

This does not make much sense to me. The Hilbert space of a CFT was built by acting $L_n$ modes onto the $|h\rangle$ primary states, where the character basically counted the number of the decedent states. How could $J_{-1}|0\rangle$ be added to the character? If $\chi^{U(1)}_0$ contained states other than the primary states and its decedents, is it still a CFT character?

What is the vector space associated with the $U(1)$ character in the $c=1$ free boson?

Comment: The state $J_{-1} \left | 0 \right >$ is a primary with respect to Virasoro but a descendant with respect to $U(1)$. Therefore it indeed belongs in $\chi_0^{U(1)}$ but not $\chi_0^{Vir}$. This comports with Sylvain's answer which says an affine module contains infinitely many Virasoro modules.